React Hook Form - dynamic controller with typescrpit
i want that fieldName will must be inside the control, so it wont work to pass a field name that not exist in the form, someone knows how to help me ?
import { Control, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

interface FieldProps {
  control: Control<any, any>;
  label: string;
  fieldName: string;
}

i was trying to use generic type but it didnt work for me

Its usually made using generic types... RHF already provides them:
import { Control, Controller, FieldValues, Path } from 'react-hook-form';

interface FieldProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues> {
  control: Control<TFieldValues>;
  label: string;
  fieldName: Path<TFieldValues>;
}

